# Generate 2d image from image3d object

Tags: image-processing, image3d

I have created a image3d from which I have rotated it to create a rotating view of the object.  I want to be able to render each 'frame' to a 2d image so that I can export the frame sequence to create a video using Export.  Can anyone help me please?

Many thanks in advance

Alan

Comment: Take a look at `Rasterize`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Would you please include an example of the code you are using to rotate the `Image3D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Rasterize[plot,"Image"]` on each frame as paw suggested.

```
img = Image3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 10, 10}]]

imageList = 
 Most@ParallelTable[
   Rasterize[
    Image3D[img, 
     ViewPoint -> {2.5 Cos[θ], 2.5 Sin[θ], 2}, 
     ViewAngle -> 30 Degree], "Image"], {θ, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01 Pi}];
ListAnimate[imageList]

Export["animation.avi", imageList];
Export["animation.gif", imageList];
```

However, `Export` already handles animations natively!  (Although not for `.gif` sadly.)

```
animation = 
  Animate[Image3D[img, 
    ViewPoint -> {2.5 Cos[θ], 2.5 Sin[θ], 2}, 
    ViewAngle -> 30 Degree], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]

Export["animation.avi", animation];
```

Comment: Thank you, the above code is exactly what I was after, I had been playing with Rasterize, but I hadn't quite hit the mark.